# React JS :Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined in children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want make a drag-drop app
but a has 1 error here

> Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined in children component

```
class DragDrop extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Item">
                <div className='Start'>
                    <div id="draggable"
                        draggable="true"
                        onDragStart={this.event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)}>
                        {this.props.item}</div>
                </div>

                <div className='div2'></div>

                <div className='div2'></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

help me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `onDragStart` to access `event`

```
onDragStart={(event) => event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)}
```

Of course, a better way to handle this is to create a separate function, for readability.

```
class DragDrop extends Component {
  dragFunction(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', null)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Item">
        <div className='Start'>
          <div id="draggable"
              draggable="true"
              onDragStart={this.dragFunction}>
              {this.props.item}</div>
        </div>

        <div className='div2'></div>
        <div className='div2'></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```